# Test average and grade

Tags: python

```
def calc_average(a,b,c,d,f):#function used to calculate average
    return (a+b+c+d+f)//5


def determine_grade(test_score):#function used to determine letter grade
    if gradeAverage > 89:
        return "A"
    elif gradeAverage > 79:
        return "B"
    elif gradeAverage > 69:
        return "C" 
    elif gradeAverage > 59:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "F"

test1 = float(input("Please enter test score for test1: "))#prompt user to enter grade
test2 = float(input("Please enter test score for test2: "))#prompt user to enter grade
test3 = float(input("Please enter test score for test3: "))#prompt user to enter grade
test4 = float(input("Please enter test score for test4: "))#prompt user to enter grade
test5 = float(input("Please enter test score for test5: "))#prompt user to enter grade

gradeAverage = calc_average(test1, test2, test3, test4, test5)#variable
finalgrade = determine_grade(gradeAverage)#variable
print(finalgrade)#display grade
print(gradeAverage)display grade letter
```

This is a problem in the "starting out with Python" book, I am supposed to calculate the average grade of 5 test  scores and give a letter grade. My problem is, I wonder if I need the variables or not. If there is a better way I would like to know.

Comment: You could use a list and a for loop (setting the `test[i]` to `float(input(...))` in each iteration of the loop) instead of the test1-test5 variables and then pass that list to calc_average.

Comment: There is a better way: write your functions so they operate on collections of grades.  Your code is far too literal.  it only works for five grades.  Your solution is more general if it can take in any number of grades.

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se].

Comment: "I wonder if I need the variables or not." And **which** variables might those be?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is done intentionally in the book to introduce `for` loops, probably in the next chapter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for loops and lists to eliminate some variables and also generalize a bit:

```
def calc_average(grades): #function used to calculate average, now takes a list
    return sum(grades)//len(grades)


grades = []
number_of_tests = int(input("input the total number of test results >>"))
for i in range(1, number_of_tests+1):
    g = int(input("input grade " + str(i) +" >>"))
    grades.append(g)

avg = calc_average(grades)
print(avg)
```

I would explain everything in detail, but I am sure your text book will soon enough tell you about "for loops", "lists", and so on. They usually start slow, and let you do unnecessary work so you can get used to the basics. Keep on reading m8 :)

(Or watch this video, in my opinion this is one of the best beginners guides out there: https://youtu.be/rfscVS0vtbw)

Answer (score 0):

Please allow me to share a few comments:

1. The function `determine_grade(test_score)` takes in a parameter `test_score`, and should be using this parameter to determine the grade, instead of the global parameter `gradeAverage`. So your code should be:

   ```
   def determine_grade(test_score):#function used to determine letter grade
       if test_score > 89:
           return "A"
       elif test_score > 79:
           return "B"
       elif test_score > 69:
           return "C"
       elif test_score > 59:
           return "D"
       else:
           return "F"
   ```
2. The calculation for average should not be a floor division `(a+b+c+d+f)//5`. This floor division formula outputs only the integer value and ignores the decimals behind. So the formula should be `(a+b+c+d+f)/5`.
3. A `for` loop would be elegant, and avoiding repeated codes. Then a list `test_list` could be used to store the test scores and be passed to the function `calc_average` to calculate the average.

The final code should look like this:

```
   def calc_average(test_list):   #function used to calculate average
       return sum(test_list)/len(test_list)

   def determine_grade(test_score):   #function used to determine letter grade
       if test_score > 89:
           return "A"
       elif test_score > 79:
           return "B"
       elif test_score > 69:
           return "C"
       elif test_score > 59:
           return "D"
       else:
           return "F"

   n = 5
   test_list = []
   for i in range(n):
       score = float(input("Please enter test score for test{}: ".format(i+1)))   #prompt user to enter grade
       test_list.append(score)

   gradeAverage = calc_average(test_list)   #variable
   finalgrade = determine_grade(gradeAverage)   #variable
   print(finalgrade)   #display grade
   print(gradeAverage)   #display grade letter
```

Output

```
Please enter test score for test1: 66
Please enter test score for test2: 77
Please enter test score for test3: 88
Please enter test score for test4: 86
Please enter test score for test5: 69
C
77.2
```